# Angular 2: Cannot read property 'unsubscribe' of undefined

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I am trying to create an `ObservableTimer` that ticks up to a certain number. I already have logic to do that, but when I try to unsubscribe from it I get a `"Cannot read property 'unsubscribe' of undefined"` error for it. 
Here is my code

```ts
syncExpireTime() {
    let route = AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT + 'Account/ExpireTime'
    this.http.get(route, this.options).map(this.extractData).catch(this.handleError).subscribe(
        res => {this.expireTime = +res},
        error => console.log(error),
        () => this.timerSub = TimerObservable.create(0,1000)
            .takeWhile(x => x <= this.expireTime)
            .subscribe(x => x == this.expireTime ? this.logout() : console.log(x))
    )
}
```

And then here is my logout code. I am trying to unsubscribe from the expiration timer when I log out

```ts
logout() {
    this.timerSub.unsubscribe()
    this.router.navigate(['./login'])
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the code where you assign timerSub is executing?

Comment: So, the observable is unsubscribing from itself?

Comment: Yes. The values are being logged onto my console, so the expression within the subscribe function is executing. I don't think the observable in unsubscribing from itself.

Answer (score 23):

There are two way which you can try to fix this issue.

```
logout() {
    if(this.timerSub){// this if will detect undefined issue of timersub
       this.timerSub.unsubscribe();
      } 
    this.router.navigate(['./login'])
}
```

or you can try ngOnDestroy lifecycle hook of angular 2 which is used to do thing when we want to destroy our component

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    if(this.timerSub){
       this.timerSub.unsubscribe();
      } 
    this.router.navigate(['./login']); 
 }
```

i hope this will help :)

Comment: I appreciate the help. I have already tried this and have just retried it. Unfortunately, It is still not unsubscribing successfully (the stream is still logging values).

Comment: fixed - added the logic for unsubscribing and it works for me.

Answer (score 4):

i had faced the same exception. it would better check "subscription.closed == false", before calling the unsubscribe().

ngOnDestroy() {

```
    // If this.notification has the multiple subscriptions 
    if(this.notifications && this.notifications.length >0)
    {
        this.notifications.forEach((s) => {
            if(!s.closed)    
                s.unsubscribe();
        });        
    }
    // if this.subscription has direct object
    if(this.subscription && !this.subscription.closed)
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should call `unsubscribe` in `ngOnDestroy`.

> #### [Lyfecicle Hooks](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html)
>
> `ngOnDestroy`
>
> Cleanup just before Angular destroys the directive/component.
> Unsubscribe observables and detach event handlers to avoid memory
> leaks.
>
> Called just before Angular destroys the directive/component.

Answer (score 0):

As reminder, this error occurs to me as well but the problem was bit different. I was trying to `unsubscribe` to subscription, which already was done via `takeUntil` rxjs operator.

This is bad design:

```
// unsubscribe = new Subject<void>(); 
const subsc = this.service.get().pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)).subscribe((value) => {});
```

Either use takeUntil OR variable to destroy subscription.

This can happen when on `ngOnDestroy` hook has:

```
this.unsubscribe$.next();
this.unsubscribe$.complete(); // these are allright
```

So when you want use `variable?.unsubscribe()`, let `takeUntil()` go.